# Installing scipy for windows 10 within my virtual environment for python 3.5

Tags: scipy, windows-10, python-3.5

I want to install scipy for my virtual environment. I have scipy when installed Anaconda but my virtual envrionment doesn't have the package. I tried pip install scipy and resulted an error.

```html
    Running from scipy source directory.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-nwih6b4a\scipy\setup.py", line 415, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-nwih6b4a\scipy\setup.py", line 411, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\users\user\pmengine\pmenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-nwih6b4a\scipy\setup.py", line 335, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "c:\users\user\pmengine\pmenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\users\user\pmengine\pmenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\users\user\pmengine\pmenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "c:\users\user\pmengine\pmenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\users\user\pmengine\pmenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\users\user\pmengine\pmenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\user\pmengine\pmenv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-nwih6b4a\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-qdxr5rtc-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\user\pmengine\pmenv\include\site\python3.5\scipy" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-nwih6b4a\scipy\
```

I tried downloading the wheel scipy-0.18.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl in my virtual environment folder and do the

```html
pip install scipy-0.18.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64
```

But it still returned

```html
(pmenv) C:\Users\user\pmengine\pmenv>pip install scipy-0.18.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
scipy-0.18.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Please help!